# Why are photons not involved in $\beta -$ decay?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radiation

Theory of $\beta  -$ emission exclusively considers participation of one $W -$ boson, one electron and one electron-antineutrino, but no photons. However Maxwell's electrodynamics require that during any change of an electromagnetic field, EM-radiation (photons) must be emitted. Spontaneous separation of two oppositely charged particles generates a variable electric dipole field which should emit EM-radiation. Moreover, as the emitted electron is strongly decelerated in the Coulomb field this also should  generate EM-radiation. However, spin angular momentum conservation would require pairwise emission of photons with mutually opposed spin (sum $+1 - 1 = 0$). To my knowledge such EM-radiation has never been reported or predicted.

Comment: Does the resultant nuclei-electron orbital change count?

Answer (score 1):

It has been reported, predicted, and even used to place an upper bound on the neutrino mass. My background is condensed matter so I may be very wrong about these sorts of particle-physics topics: but I believe the presence of a large nucleus nearby probably breaks your expectation of pairwise emission. (Pairwise emission is however a well-known and common feature of positron annihilation, where the opposite-directionality is used by PET scanners to filter out high-energy photons coming from non-positron sources.)

The reason that a first romp through the literature might not have revealed this to you is most likely that you do not have a particle physics background; this sort of electron-braking radiation is known to particle physicists by its German name *bremsstrahlung* even in English publications. More specifically the bremsstrahlung from the inside of the nucleus is known as "inner bremsstrahlung"; this search phrase leads to many discussions of the phenomenon, and even a mention on Wikipedia.